# Name a JS Function by clientId

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following control on my page:

```
        <abc:OrcaShowHidePanelExtender ID="NumberPlate" ShowHideControlID="RadioButtonListNumberPlate"
            TargetControlID="panelNumberPlate" runat="server" 
            ShowHideClientPredicate="NumberPlate_ClientPredicate" />
```

So this is used to hide/show a panel on screen.  The problem now is I have 3 tabs and I need to show hide the panel on the 3 tabs which are on the same page.

```
        function NumberPlate_ClientPredicate() {

            return $('#<%= RadioButtonListNumberPlate.ClientID %> input:radio:checked').val() === 'Yes';
}
```

My question is can I add Client Id to the function so the each panel would call the function idependently as it only calls for the final panel at the minute

so I tried the below but with no success:

```
 function  $('#<%= NumberPlate_ClientPredicate.ClientID %>')() {
//my return check
}
```

Comment: Can't you have one function with an if/switch using the 1st param? Or an object of functions: `myFuncs={};myFuncs[getid()]=func()..;myFuncs[getid()]=func()..`

Comment: Why not pass the clientid to the function?  Have it figure out what to do based on the parameter?

Comment: What @SmokeyPHP says. But if you do need to generate custom function names - do it server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i just used:

<%= this.ClientID %> before the function name and taking ShowHideClientPredicate="NumberPlate_ClientPredicate" off the panel worked for me and then adding the name in code behind